# All data is not displayed from SQL server to the websit.e

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am trying to display just the building names from the SQL server database on a webpage. But the webpage is only showing the first name repeatedly, with the correct count of buildings.

C# : -

On Page Load.

```
// Fetching the total count of buildings from the database and storing it in a variable.

            SqlConnection conBldng = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-PMQQD94\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=loginAMS;Integrated Security=True");

            conBldng.Open();

            SqlCommand cmdBldngs = new SqlCommand("Select buildingName from roomData", conBldng);

            //var countBdlngs = cmdBldngs;

            //conBldng.Close();

            // Now to show the building names.

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-PMQQD94\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=loginAMS;Integrated Security=True");
            
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select buildingName from buildingData", conn);

            conn.Open();

            string data = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {

                var p = new HtmlGenericControl("a") { InnerText = data };

                inputBuilding.Controls.Add(p);

                p.Attributes.Add("class", "card");

                p.Attributes.Add("href", "viewRooms.aspx");

            }

            conn.Close();
```

ASP.NET: -

```
<div class="cards" id="inputBuilding" runat="server">



</div>
```

Generated output: -

[Generated Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvYMg.png)

I want to retrieve all the names of just the buildings from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're getting the row from the DataReader, but you're then ignoring it when you render.  And you don't seem to need that `ExecuteScalar` step.

Using `dr.GetString()` should help you get your value.

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    var p = new HtmlGenericControl("a") { InnerText = dr.GetString(0) };
    inputBuilding.Controls.Add(p);
    p.Attributes.Add("class", "card");
    p.Attributes.Add("href", "viewRooms.aspx");
}
```

There are some good simple examples of using the DataReader here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader